# React native How to validate username and password

Tags: validation, react-native

I want to validate username and password,then I want to display error below input field.

I have given already in alert form,but I need to display error below input field.

If anyone knows please let me know.

```
 if( uname == '' && pwd == '' || uname == '' || pwd =='' || uname =="true" && pwd == '') {
       if(uname == ''){
        alert('Username is required');
       } 
      else
        {
        alert('Password is required');
        }

      // alert('This value is required');  
    }
    else{
      alert('Invalid username/password');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### put one `<Text>` element below `<TextInput>`

take one state `errorMessage` and use it in `<Text>`

when you want to display error set the message in `errorMessage`

ane when not set it `null`

Comment: can you please give me a sample code,because am new to react native.@Jaydeep Galani

Comment: @Aswini you can find codes in google. if you got an error then you can ask for help here. if you are new i will suggest you to learn from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial or http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

i have given code to reach that question functionality

```
this.state ={
error : ''
}

 const { username, password } = this.state;
      if(username == ''){
        this.setState({error:'Username is required'});
        }
        else if(password == ''){
          this.setState({error:'Password is required'});
        }
        else{     
        this.setState({error: null}) 
 }

<Text style={styles.error}>
            {this.state.error}
 </Text>
```